# Apache Ignite: What are the dependencies of IgniteHadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystem?

Tags: hadoop, ignite

I am trying to setup IGFS with Hadoop as the secondary storage. I have set my configuration as shown [here](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.0/docs/igfs-secondary-file-system) but I keep getting `NoClassDefFoundError`s. I have downloaded both binary distributions of Ignite and have tried building from source also but the dependencies are not included. `hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar` and `ignite-hadoop-1.4.0.jar` provided some of the dependencies but now I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf` which by my understanding is a deprecated class...

I have been following the instructions on the Apache Ignite website but this is as far as I've gotten.

What dependencies do I need for IgniteHadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystem as the secondary storage?

Comment: My Ignite version is 1.4.0 and my Hadoop version is 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that Ignite node does not have Hadoop libraries on the classpath. To fix that please try to do the following:

1) use "Hadoop Accelerator" edition of Ignite distribution (use -Dignite.edition=hadoop if you're building the distribution yourself).

2) Set HADOOP_HOME environment variable for the Ignite process if you're using Apache Hadoop distribution, or, if you use another distribution (HDP, Cloudera, BigTop, etc.) make sure /etc/default/hadoop file exists and has appropriate contents.

Alternatively, you can manually add necessary Hadoop dependencies to Ignite node classpath: these are dependencies of groupId "org.apache.hadoop" listed in file modules/hadoop/pom.xml . Currently they are:

1. hadoop-annotations
2. hadoop-auth
3. hadoop-common
4. hadoop-hdfs
5. hadoop-mapreduce-client-common
6. hadoop-mapreduce-client-core

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to deal with dependency management yourself - which is a real hard thing to do manually - I'd suggest you look at the projects providing orchestration and deployment services for software stacks. Check Apache Bigtop (bigtop.apache.org), that provides pre-cut linux packages for Apache Ignite, Hadoop, HDFS and pretty much anything else in this space. You can grab the latest nightly packages from our CI at http://ci.bigtop.apache.org/view/Packages/job/Bigtop-trunk-packages